# how does std::map work for counting duplicates

Tags: c++, dictionary, duplicates

I'm a beginner in cp and recently I have stumbled upon a [problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1003/problem/A) which I couldn't solve using vector, thus i've checked the solution and saw most of the codes had map in it. Can someone explain how is the std::map working in this particular problem. This is one of the solutions below :

```
int main()
{
    int n,mx=0,cnt=0,i,x;
    cin>>n;
    map<int,int>mp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      cin>>x;
      mp[x]++;
      if(mp[x]>mx)
      {
        mx=mp[x];
      }
    }
    cout<<mx<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `map` data structure, also commonly referred to as a _dictionary_, maps a _key_ to a _value_, where the types of these respective entities needn't necessarily be the same. A common exercise could be to count the of duplicate words (say, `std::string`) in a text, in which case for each parsed word, say `std::string`, you would increment an integer value for the _key-value pair_ associated with that _key_ `std::string`. When finding a new word it is simply added to the dictionary as `{word, 1}` - namely a word that has occurred once.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is a structure that associates one value to one unique key.

The net effect of that is that each distinct key can have only one value.

So in case of `map<int, int> mp`, the value associated with `mp[123]` is one integer. In C++ maps auto-create non-existent elements, so upon first access the value associated with `mp[123]` will be value-initialized to `0` and you can safely count using `mp[x]++`.

Having said that, with `int` keys the same effect can be achieved using a simple array. If the key is dense and the maximum key value is known, you can just allocate the array(vector) and use the key as the index into it. A map is useful when keys are sparse, non-numeric, or when the range is unknown.

In your particular case the range of keys seems to be [1 .. 100]. That can be solved using an array. A map isn't needed.

```
int main()
{
    int n, mx = 0, x;
    cin >> n;
    int mp[101]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> x; // 1 <= x <= 100 according to problem definition
        mx = max(mx, ++mp[x]);
    }
    cout << mx << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mp` is a count of how many times each number has been seen in the input so far. It is a sequence of pairs of numbers, with the first (the "key") being taken from the input, and the second (the "value") being the count. In this program we don't care, but these pairs are ordered by the key.

Each time round the loop, `mp[x]++;` adds one to the count for the number `x`. If the number hasn't been seen before, it increments 0 to 1, because 0 is the value of a defaultly initialised `int`.

Then `mx` is set to the larger of itself and the updated count for `x`.